# Swift - json nested array not returning value

Tags: arrays, json, swift, server, nested

I am trying to grab the array from "imports" from the JSON file but the array is returning encoded.

[ServerName.JSONNodeValue, ServerName.JSONNodeValue, ServerName.JSONNodeValue, ServerName.JSONNodeValue, ServerName.JSONNodeValue, ServerName.JSONNodeValue]

I know the data can be seen as if I print the value of the data in the JSONNode file, it comes up as 
https://servername.com/storage/sessions/00167/imports
(
    "movie1.mov",
    "movie3.mov",
    "movie2.mov",
    "._movie1.mov",
    "._movie2.mov",
    "._movie3.mov"
)

This isn't my code and the reason why I am struggling as I am still pretty new at swift.

My JSON file looks similar to this.

```
{
 "id": 135
 "name": Test
 "angles" [
{
 "id": 35,
 "name": "test",
 "mp4": "http:/0.0.0:3000/storage/seesion/00138/url.mp4"
}
 ]
 "imports" [
  movie1.mp4,
  movie2.mp4,
  movie3.mp4
 ]
}
```

Swift Code - Session File

```
struct Session {
var id: Int
var name: String
var angles: [Angle] = []
var imports: [Any]

extension Session {
init(fromDict dict: [String: AnyObject]){
    let node = JSONNodeValue(dict)
    let sessionId = node["id"].int ?? 0
    self.id = sessionId
    self.name = node["name"].string ?? "???"
    print(name)
    self.imports = node["imports"].arrayOrEmpty
    self.angles = node["angles"].arrayOrEmpty.map { angleDict in
        Angle(fromDict: angleDict.object!)
    }
```

JSONnode file that handles the JSON

```
protocol JSONNode {
subscript(key: String) -> JSONNode { get }
var int: Int? { get }
var double: Double? { get }
var string: String? { get }
var bool: Bool? { get }
var date: Date? { get }
var array: [JSONNode]? { get }
var arrayOrEmpty: [JSONNode] { get }
var object: [String: Any]? { get }
var objectOrEmpty: [String: Any] { get }
}

class JSONNodeValue : JSONNode {
static func parse (_ data: Data) -> JSONNode {
    if let root = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) {
        return JSONNodeValue(root)
    } else {
        return JSONNodeNone.instance
    }
}

var value: Any

init(_ value: Any) {
    self.value = value
    print(value) // SHOWS THE DATA I NEED
}

subscript(key: String) -> JSONNode {
    if let object = value as? [String: Any], let subvalue = object[key] {
        return JSONNodeValue(subvalue)
    } else {
        return JSONNodeNone.instance
    }
}

var int: Int? {
    return value as? Int
}

var double: Double? {
    return value as? Double
}

var string: String? {
    return value as? String
}

var bool: Bool? {
    return value as? Bool
}

var date: Date? {
    if let formatted = string {
        return Date.fromIso8601(formatted)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

var array: [JSONNode]? {
    if let array = value as? [Any] {
        return array.map { JSONNodeValue($0) }
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

var arrayOrEmpty: [JSONNode] {
    return array ?? []
}

var object: [String: Any]? {
    return value as? [String: Any]
}

var objectOrEmpty: [String : Any] {
    return object ?? [:]
}
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction or to other answered questions that could help me solve this? Thanks

Comment: Isn't this `node["imports_dir_contents"].arrayOrEmpty` should be `node["imports"].arrayOrEmpty` ?

Comment: Thanks, Amit. Sorry, it was a typo and corrected it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved what I was trying to achieve by adding a new a variable in the JSNODE file which then gave me ["movie1.mov", "movie3.mov", "movie2.mov", "._movie1.mov", "._movie2.mov", "._movie3.mov"]

```
var arrayList: [String]? {
        return value as? [String]
    }
```

Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

The struct looks good, but remove the `= []` after `[Angle]`, but you should use `Codable` protocol to parse the JSON like so:

```
struct Session: Codable {
var id: Int
var name: String
var angles: [Angle]
var imports_dir_contents: [Any]
```

then create another struct to get the Angle

```
struct Angle: Codable
let id: Int
let name: String
let mp4: String
```

Then you want to parse using the `Codable` protocol method by passing in the data retrieved from the networking call.

```
do {

     let newJSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
     let session = try newJSONDecoder.decode(Session.self, from:data)

     let anglesArray = session.angles // or use whatever array property you want 


     } catch {
       print("error while parsing:\(error)")
     }
```

Comment: I am sorry I realised I did a typo. I am trying to get the import content which I wrote "import_dir_contents" instead of 'imports"